# Cartesian Equations for the Subspace

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, independence

I would really appreciate some help with trying to find the Cartesian equation of a subspace (part b). Have attached my answers. Thank you very much in advanced[image: ![my workings out and the question]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlMx7.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be two parameters, since it is spanned by two linearly independent vectors:
$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=s\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\0\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}s+t\\2s\\t\end{pmatrix}.$$
This gives you $s=y/2$, $t=z$. Plugging this into the equation for $x$, we get $x=y/2+z$.

Comment: Thank you ever so much! Fantastic! Just realised that I just wrote out the line that passes through those two points, rather than the 2-d subspace as you have shown!

Comment: I.e. the hyperplan in $\mathds{R}^3$

Comment: @Andy: right, what you wrote is the line passing through the two points.